# Page view layout bug on one site of multisite using same code

Tags: multistore, ce-1.9.1.0

I am absolutely stumped on this one. I run a mutlisite installation which has several websites.

2 of the websites use exactly the same template (ultimo) but for some reason on product view one of the websites tabs, add to cart and sticky menu have broken.

There has been no recent changes to any code or upgrades either that would affect this and as I said they use exactly the same code and have been working find up until this point. The only difference between the 2 sites is you must log in to see pricing and buy on one of the two sites.

Here is exactly the same product on each site to compare:

http://satsecure.uk/maxx-digital-round-junction-box-size-80-x-50mm-ip44-white.html
http://shopmassive.com/store/maxx-digital-round-junction-box-size-80-x-50mm-ip44-white.html

It's almost like javascript has stopped working on shopmassive product pages. I've had a look in exceptions log but there's nothing in there and also flushed the cache and reindexed the sites.

Update:

I have discovered that the probable cause of this is due to the fact that one of the websites is trying to load 2 versions of jQuery whilst the other is not and I have no idea how to track down where this additional jQuery code is originating from. The extra code being inserted is after product data and cookie info but before footer:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Anyone know how I can find where this is coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out in my case that a module was adding second version of Jquery deep in the product page. It was a case of finding which module was adding Jquery and removing the entry.

Answer (score 0):

If you run developer console on chrome on each site, and refresh the page, you can see that the debugger will catch an exception on shopmassive.com.

Line 367 in app.js:

```
  // ==============================================
// Blocks collapsing on all viewports
// ==============================================

//Exclude elements with ".mobile-collapsible" for backward compatibility
$j('.collapsible:not(.mobile-collapsible) .block-title').toggleSingle();
```

Paused on exception: ‘TypeError: $j(…).toggleSingle is not a function

Comment: I can see these errors but why would they occur so much on one site but not the other? They both use the same files with shopmassive being the main domain and satsecure is symlinks.